# Falha na comparação de datas antes de gravar no banco

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando fazer uma validação de datas, se a data `DataInicial` for menor que a `DataAtual`, ou seja, não pode ser retroativa o script deveria me retornar uma mensagem de erro com `json_encode` não permitindo que o fluxo continue, o que não está acontecendo.
O que fiz foi isso, vejam:

```
 if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'Inserir') { 

    $IdColaborador = $_POST['IdColaborador'];
    $IdUnidade = $_POST['IdUnidade'];
    $IdDepartamento = $_POST['IdDepartamento']; 

    // DATA ATUAL
    $DataAtual = date('Y-m-d');

    // FORMATANDO A DATA PARA GRAVAÇÃO NO BD    
    $DataInicial = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['dDataInicial']))); // converte datas em formato 'br' para sql.
    $DataFinal = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['dDataFinal']))); // converte datas em formato 'br' para sql.  

    // VERIFICANDO SE DATA É RETROATIVA
    if ( strtotime($DataInicial) < strtotime($DataAtual) ) {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "A data não pode ser retroativa";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";   
    }

    $dHoraInicial = $_POST['dHoraInicial'];
    $dHoraFinal = $_POST['dHoraFinal'];
    $sAssunto = $_POST['sAssunto'];
    $sLocal = $_POST['sLocal']; 
    $sDescricao = $_POST['sDescricao'];

    mysql_select_db($database_pcon, $pcon);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO agendaMural (IdColaborador, IdUnidade, IdDepto, DataInicial, HoraInicial, DataFinal, HoraFinal, Assunto, Local, Descricao ) VALUES ('$IdColaborador', '$IdUnidade', '$IdDepartamento', '$DataInicial', '$dHoraInicial', '$DataFinal', '$dHoraFinal', '$sAssunto', '$sLocal', '$sDescricao')";
    $query = @mysql_query($sql,$pcon);

    if ($query) {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro inserido com sucesso";
    } else {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error($pcon);
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }
}

// FECHA CONEXÃO COM BD
mysql_close($pcon);

// RETORNAR STATUS - MENSAGEM DA EXECUÇÃO
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($aretorno);
```

Comment: Isso aqui ta errado: `if ( strtotime($DataInicial) " . mysql_error($pcon);` não deveria ser uma `{` ?

Comment: Olá @rray, na minha visualização, antes de publicar o código aparece certo, mas depois de publicado fica com esse erro, vou editar.

Comment: Creio que ```strtotime($DataInicial)```, seja desnecessário, já que a atribuição da variável já é um tipo ```date```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode verificar se data é retroativa com a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), através da propriedade [invert](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert), ao retornar `1` significa que o resultado do calculo é negativo se for `0` é positivo, use [diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) para efetuar o calculo de diferença entre as datas.

```
<?php

$hoje = new DateTime();
$dataInicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/11/2015');

$resultado = $hoje->diff($dataInicial);

if($resultado->invert){
    echo 'data retroativa';
}else{
    echo 'data no periodo';
}
```

Comment: Interessante esse `->invert`. A variavel `$resultado` retorna um booleano?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe `$resultado` é um [dateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: Olá @rray, com o posso usar a variável que vem do meu formulário nessa linha? $dataInicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/11/2015'); No local onde está coloco minha variável?

Comment: @adventistapr, isso pode trocar aquela data fixa por uma variavel. Se precisar converte ela para gravar no banco faça: `$dataInicial->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Olá @rray, muito obrigado pela excelente dica e ajuda, o código ficou perfeito.

Comment: @adventistapr código simples é a ideia :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$hoje = new DateTime();
$dataInicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/11/201<?php

$hoje = new DateTime();
$dataInicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/11/2015');

$resultado = $hoje->diff($dataInicial);

if($resultado->invert){
    echo 'data retroativa';
}else{
    echo 'data no periodo';
}5');

$resultado = $hoje->diff($dataInicial);

if($resultado->invert){
    echo 'data retroativa';
}else{
    echo 'data no periodo';
}
```

E se neste exemplo do invert eu quiser colocar um else if pra se a data for igual eu colocar um evo tipo "Em dia" ?